# golang framework gin problemas al ejecutar govendor fetch

Tags: web, go

Estoy probando el siguiente gin que es un framework de go

https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin

El proceso de instalación lleva los siguientes pasos:

*Go get govendor*

```
$ go get github.com/kardianos/govendor
```

*Create your project folder and cd inside*

```
$ mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/myusername/project && cd "$_"
```

*Vendor init your project and add gin*

```
$ govendor init
```

Pero el problema es que al ejecutar la siguiente instrucción:

```
govendor fetch github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.2
```

Me tira el siguiente error en la terminal:

```
# cd /home/usuario/go/.cache/govendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin; git fetch
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed
Error: failed to download repo into "/home/usuario/go/.cache/govendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin" exit status 128
Failed to fetch package "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
github.com/kardianos/govendor/context.(*Context).Alter
        /home/usuario/go/src/github.com/kardianos/govendor/context/modify.go:712
github.com/kardianos/govendor/run.(*runner).Modify
        /home/usuario/go/src/github.com/kardianos/govendor/run/modify.go:152
github.com/kardianos/govendor/run.(*runner).run
        /home/usuario/go/src/github.com/kardianos/govendor/run/run.go:98
github.com/kardianos/govendor/run.Run
        /home/usuario/go/src/github.com/kardianos/govendor/run/run.go:44
main.main
        /home/usuario/go/src/github.com/kardianos/govendor/main.go:35
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:198
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361
```

Alguien me puede decir que es lo me falta o que es lo que estoy haciendo mal

la versión de go que estoy usando es:

go version go1.10.1 linux/amd64

Comment: Parece que es un problema de conexión segura. ¿Puedes acceder a https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/ desde el navegador ?

Comment: si, pero que otra cosa puedo intentar

Comment: mm.. ¿y si haces ping desde la terminal ?  ¿tu conexión está detrás de un proxy? puede que esta respuesta te ayude: https://askubuntu.com/a/187199

Answer (score 0):

Solo como prueba.
Trata de hacer el fetch de la dependencia a mano, y luego vuelve a compilar.

```
go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

Si el error persiste, comparte el 'git pull' del repo con mayor detalle para entender un poco mejor cual es el inconveniente el arealizar el SSLHandShake